# How do you redirect URLs with a query string to another host?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, querystring

This htaccess snippet is supposed to redirect

myhost.com/?p=1&preview=true

to

alt.myhost.com/?p=1&preview=true

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myhost.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/\?p=([0-9]+)&preview=true$ http://alt.myhost.com/?p=$1&preview=true [NC,R=301,L]
```

but for some reason I can't escape the / and ? part of the URL. Not sure why this isnt working...

I've tried escaping ?

```
\\? \? [?]
```

and I've tried escaping the /

```
\\/ \/ [/]
```

none of these seem to work either...

help!

Comment: `RewriteRule` does not work with query strings (everything after `?`) only with url path (which you basically do not have in your example). Are you trying to redirect **ALL** URLs from one domain to another or just this one?

Comment: Just the one =/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will redirect ALL requests from myhost.com to alt.myhost.com

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^alt\.myhost\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://alt.myhost.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

Code taken from official [mod_rewrite manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html#canonicalhost)

**If** for whatever reason the query string is not get preserved, replace the last line by

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://alt.myhost.com/$1 [L,R,NE,QSA]
```

---

**UPDATE:** This will redirect your specific URL to another domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =myhost.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(p=1&preview=true)
RewriteRule ^$ http://alt.myhost.com/?%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Well I dont want all requests, I only need that specific URL redirected to another domain and not any others.

Comment: @codeninja I have updated my answer. Redirect will work for that URL only.

Comment: @LazyOne will this work with postname permalinks too? Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Because of the query string "p=([0-9]+)&preview=true" I guess your need for a redirect is due to having wordpress admin on a subdomain and the website on your main domain.

Because of that you can't preview drafts.

I came up with a broader solution that also works with custom post types and plugins that add parameters:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =myhost.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (preview=true)
RewriteRule ^$ http://alt.myhost.com/?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

In plain english when "preview=true" is found in a query, the redirection happen to the alt subdomain and the full query is kept.

Comment: Hi, this is brilliant. Would this work for postname permalinks too?

Comment: Solution is great but it preview value is "truee" or "truenotsotrue", this thing still works when it shouldn't be. In other words, it doesn't match EXACT query string value